# How to add local variable to PL/SQL INSERT INTO using subquery

Tags: plsql, subquery, insert-into

I have an Oracle PL/SQL question.  I have an INSERT INTO that works fine:

```
DECLARE
   l_filename   VARCHAR2 (1024);      
BEGIN
   l_filename := 'some value';
     INSERT INTO aff_attach
        (file_id, file_name, mime_type, attachment, file_size)
        SELECT ID, l_filename, mime_type, blob_content,DOC_SIZE
          FROM apex_application_files
          WHERE filename = l_filename AND created_by = :app_user;
END:
```

Now in the same INSERT INTO statement I'd like to include another field into aff_attach (AFF_EVENT_FKEY).  That value will not come from the SELECT statement.  If I define l_aff_event_fkey, and prior to the Insert statement I assign l_aff_event_fkey a value of 9, How can I include that in the Insert Into statement?
Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be added to the SELECT statement (as a constant in the SELECT):

```
DECLARE

   l_filename   VARCHAR2 (1024);
   v_aff_event_fk NUMBER;

BEGIN
   l_filename := 'some value';
   v_aff_event_fk := 9;

     INSERT INTO aff_attach
        (file_id, file_name, mime_type, attachment, file_size, AFF_EVENT_FKEY)
        SELECT ID, l_filename, mime_type, blob_content,DOC_SIZE, v_aff_event_fk
          FROM apex_application_files
          WHERE filename = l_filename AND created_by = :app_user;
END:
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks!